# Derivation of the BCS Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, superconductivity, hamiltonian

$$ 
\hat{H}_{\mathrm{BCS}}=\sum_{k \sigma} \varepsilon_{k} c_{k \sigma}^{\dagger} c_{k \sigma}-\sum_{k k^{\prime}} G_{k k^{\prime}} c_{k \uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{-k \downarrow}^{\dagger} c_{-k^{\prime} \downarrow} c_{k^{\prime} \uparrow}
 $$

Any books on how to derive it?

I get that the first part is the Hamiltonian of an electron and the second describes the creation of Cooper pairs, but the text I'm reading simply gives it and I was wondering how was it derived, I can't seem to find a satisfactory online text.

Comment: Try searching for Fröhlich Hamiltonian. The interaction term is an effective potential induced by lattice phonons.